# Admin login - $_SESSION is not defined properly

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, admin

**How do I define my $_SESSION['amyusername']; and $_SESSION['amypassword']; properly?**

**Full code:**

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "login";
$tbl_name = "medlemmer";

if ($_POST['amyusername'] && $_POST['amypassword']) {
    //Opret forbindelse til Databasen via MySQL.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("Kunne ikke oprette forbindelse til databasen!");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name");

        $amyusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amyusername']);
        $amypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amypassword']);
        $amypassword = md5($amypassword);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Brugernavn = '$amyusername' AND Password = '$amypassword' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);    
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            if($row["Rank"] == "C") {
            $_SESSION['amyusername'];
            $_SESSION['amypassword'];
            header("Location: admin_success.php");
            }
            else {
                echo "Du er ikke Admin!";
                header("refresh: 3, admin.php");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Indtast et gyldig ADMIN login";
        header("refresh: 3, admin.php");
    }


} 
else {
    echo "Du skal indtaste et brugernavn og password!";
    header("refresh: 3, admin.php");

}


?>
```

**Where the code isn't defined properly:**

```
if($row["Rank"] == "C") {
   $_SESSION['amyusername'];
   $_SESSION['amypassword'];
   header("Location: admin_success.php");
}
```

It just passes through and lets everybody in no matter if they are admin or nor.
I've tried for 3 hours getting it to work. It might be because $SESSION['amyusername']; and $SESSION['amypassword']; is not defined properly or what? I do not know what I should do.

Comment: Where are you setting the values you're putting in to your query? Have you done any debugging to see what's going on? Are your queries even succeeding?

Comment: I have updated the code, still I think $SESSION['amyusername']; and $SESSION['amypassword']; is not defined properly.

Comment: Please do not use mysql_* functions in new code, they are deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.0beta1/NEWS#L186

Comment: Is that why it causes problems or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Brugernavn = '$amyusername' AND Password = '$amypassword' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);    
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($count == 1) {
    if($row["Rank"] == "C") {
        $_SESSION['amyusername'] = "$amyusername";
        header("Location: admin_success.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Du er ikke Admin!";
        header("refresh: 3, admin.php");
    }
}
else {
    echo "Indtast et gyldig ADMIN login";
    header("refresh: 3, admin.php");
}
```

**This fixed my problem!!**

```
$_SESSION['amyusername'] = "$amyusername";
```

By defining the $_SESSION properly... I'm so dumb.

Answer (score 1):

You're not limiting the rank by the username in the $rsql query. If both username and rank are in the same table, then just check $result for Rank instead of running a whole new query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Comment: Well it still doesn't do what it is suppose to... It might be because my $SESSION['amyusername']; and $SESSION['amypassword']; is not defined properly?